# How do I return strong type object in Linq?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have a stored proc that returns a list of users (rows in User table).

```
var admins = db.aspnet_UsersInRoles_GetUsersInRoles('/', "Admin");
```

LINQ generated aspnet_User classes for me, so can I somehow map the result to a List of aspnet_User type? Something like:

```
List<aspnet_User> admins =  db.aspnet_UsersInRoles_GetUsersInRoles('/', "Admin");
```

Here is a [capture of what is returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9KQf.png).

Comment: Well what type does `aspnet_UsersInRoles_GetUsersInRoles` return?

Answer (score 2):

It's entirely possible that you just need:

```
List<aspnet_User> admins =  db.aspnet_UsersInRoles_GetUsersInRoles('/', "Admin")
                              .ToList();
```

But it's hard to know without seeing what type the method call returns.

Comment: aspnet_UsersInRoles_GetUsersInRoles returns ISingleResult<aspnet_UsersInRoles_GetUsersInRolesResult>

Comment: @dev.e.loper: Hmm. And what does `aspnet_UsersInRoles_GetUsersInRolesResult` have in it?

Comment: Looks like there are two objects in ResultView.  http://i.stack.imgur.com/V9KQf.png

Comment: @dev.e.loper: Well it looks like it's providing a sequence of `aspnet_UsersInRoles_GetUsersInRolesResult` instead of `aspnet_User`... are those good enough for you?

Comment: @Jon Skeet: shouldn't you avoid using aspnet_User completely? It is an internal part of the membership provider..

Comment: @Pleun: I don't know, to be honest - this isn't something I've ever done myself...

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this should be a comment but it is way too long...

Well, you do not really want the internal class `<aspnet_User>` you should want a `MembershipUser`.

So how about not using the stored procedure that comes with the membership provider but really use the Membership provider itsself.

There is a beautiful class: Roles in System.Web.Security

And it gives you this:

```
public static string[] GetUsersInRole(string roleName)
```

From here, a foreach to get the MembershipUser(s) in a list is not that complicated.

Answer (score 1):

By default a stored procedure will return a type that it determines based on the output columns with Result tacked on to the end. It doesn't associate it with types you have already determined. To change this, you can either change the Return Type in the property window to the type you have already defined in your model, or when dragging the stored proc into your model, drop it directly on the type that you want the stored proc to be mapped into.

You don't get the opportunity to change the column mappings for stored procs however, so make sure the shape that the stored proc generates is the same as your target object structures.

Answer (score 0):

It's an old post and I was working on it today and I get the same issue,

I think you are requesting asp membership ?

You can not convert this stored procedure to aspnet_User because it returns aspnet_UsersInRoles_GetUsersInRolesResult type.

but from this aspnet_UsersInRoles_GetUsersInRolesResult you can get userName, then request the aspnet_User table:

```
    String app = "your application name";
    String role = "your role name";

    ArrayList userInRoleList = new ArrayList();

    //Get the role ID
    ASPNETDBDataContext aspDB = new ASPNETDBDataContext();

    var userInRole = aspDB.aspnet_UsersInRoles_GetUsersInRoles(app, role);

    foreach (aspnet_UsersInRoles_GetUsersInRolesResult users in userInRole)
    {
        userInRoleList.Add(users.UserName);
    }
```